# Remove raster layers with many NAs from rasterstack

Tags: r, raster

I've a `RasterStack` with several thousand layers. However, some of the layers have a lot of NAs so I would to exclude those layers by setting a threshold. I did it correctly using a `for` loop, but this is very slow. I was trying to do it with `calc`, but my function failed. Here are my trials and I would appreciate any hint in order to make the processing faster.

```
library(raster)
lst<-stack(r1,r2,r3,r4) # 
lst_new<-stack()
for (i in 1: nlayers(lst)){
   # total number of cells without NA
   no_NA<-length(lst[[i]][!is.na(lst[[i]])]) #
   if(no_NA >= 14652){ # 97% 
     l<-lst[[i]]
     lst_new<-stack(lst_new,l)
     }
   }
  #This code works OK but slow for big rasterstack. So I tried the
  # following using calc function    
  remove.badL<-function(x){
          no_NA<-length(x[is.na(x)])
          if(no_NA >= 14652){
          return(x)
          }
         }
  lst_new<-calc(lst,fun=remove.badL) 
# this is the error I got
```

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
    unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeValues’ for   signature ‘"RasterBrick", "NULL"’

I would appreciate any suggestions. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellStats` might not always be the best option when dealing with huge datasets. Extending @jbaums sample data to `n = 100` layers, for instance, takes quite some time on my machine.

```
## sample data, n = 100
library(raster)

set.seed(10)
s <- stack(replicate(100, raster(matrix(runif(1e6), 1e3))))
s[s > 0.95] <- NA

## set na limit (e.g., 5% of all cells)
limit <- 0.05 * ncell(s)


### cellStats -----

system.time(
  id1 <- cellStats(is.na(s), sum) < limit
)
# user  system elapsed 
# 28.794   0.253  29.050
```

Instead of using `cellStats`, you could *e.g.* create the index vector that indicates low amounts of missing data manually using a parallelized `foreach`.

```
### parallel version -----

## open parallel backend
library(doParallel)
cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
registerDoParallel(cl)

## loop over layers in parallel
system.time(
  id2 <- foreach(i = unstack(s), .packages = "raster", 
                 .combine = "c") %dopar% {
                   sum(is.na(i[])) < limit
                 }
)
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.337   0.005   3.802
```

As you can see, the latter approach performs considerably faster and, at the same time, returns identical results.

```
## similarity check
identical(as.logical(id1), id2)
[1] TRUE
```

The only thing left to do then is close the parallel backend

```
## deregister parallel backend
stopCluster(cl)
```

and create a subset of `s` based on the derived index vector.

```
## data subset
s[[which(id2)]]
```

Comment: +1 - that's a nice speed boost. But the bottleneck is not `cellStats`. If you replace your `sum(is.na(i[])) < limit` with `cellStats(is.na(i), sum) < limit` you'll have equivalent performance (each is ~2.96 sec on my system).

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it, with `is.na`, `cellStats`, and a conditional `RasterStack` subset.

First, lets create some example data:

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(replicate(10, raster(matrix(runif(1e6), 1e3))))
s[s > 0.95] <- NA # insert some NAs
```

We can return the number of `NA` cells per layer with:

```
cellStats(is.na(s), sum)
```

With that knowledge, we can use those counts in a subsetting operation:

```
thr <- 14652
s2 <- s[[which(cellStats(is.na(s), sum) < thr)]]
```

Layers with less than `thr` (here, 14652) `NA` cells will be retained in the new stack, `s2`, while those with more `NA`s will be ditched.

---

Applying all this to your data, you should be able to use:

```
lst_new <- lst[[cellStats(is.na(lst), sum) < 14652]]
```

Comment: Wrong. `Error in .local(x, ...) : not a valid subset` is due to the fact that you are providing a `logical` index vector. Wrap it inside `which` and no error will be thrown at all, *i.e.* even if none of the layers in `s` matches the specified criterion.

Comment: @fdetsch - mind elaborating on which part of my statement is wrong?

Comment: Sure @jbaums. For instance, if you insert `set.seed(10)` (to create identical sample data) and specify `thr <- 50000`, then the result of `cellStats(is.na(s), sum) < thr` is `c(T, F, T, F, T, F, F, T, F, F)`, *i.e.* some of the layers match the criterion, and some don't. However, `s[[cellStats(is.na(s), sum) < thr]]` still throws `Error in .local(x, ...) : not a valid subset`. Instead, `s[[which(cellStats(is.na(s), sum) < thr)]]` solves the issue.

Comment: To clarify my position, see `?stack`. Let's assume you define `fn <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"); st <- stack(fn, fn)`, then this will work: `st[[which(c(TRUE, FALSE))]]` (or, alternatively, `st[[1]]`), whereas this will throw the above error: `st[[c(TRUE, FALSE)]]`.

Comment: Thank you @ Jbaums and fdetsch. wrapping with "which' is needed for Jbaums suggestion to work smoothly. Yet the Suggestion by fdetsch is fast when I used it on my data.

Comment: @Tade, then you should probably consider accepting an answer in order to close this issue.

Comment: @fdetsch - you're right. The perils of posting at 4 am.

Comment: @jbaums, no offense meant. I wouldn't have thought that `logical` indices fail when trying to subset a `RasterStack` until I tested your code myself.